# Fedora alternative to the post-up command

Tags: fedora, network-interface

Does Fedora support something similar to the *post-up* command ([as in Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man5/interfaces.5.html)) or does it have any other alternative for this command?

I want to run a custom script after activating network interface but I have no idea how to manage that in Fedora.

> ```
> post-up command
>
>          Run command after bringing the interface up.   If  this  command
>          fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as
>          configured (even though it has really been  configured),  prints
>          an  error  message,  and exits with status 0.  This behavior may
>          change in the future.
> ```

Comment: I suspect you'll have to do something using either Systemd or NetworkManager to get this functionality. http://askubuntu.com/questions/13963/call-script-after-connecting-to-a-wireless-network.

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to put a script in this directory: `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`. NetworkManager will run scripts in alphabetical order when various network events occur.

*[excerpt: from the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/networkmanager):*

> NetworkManager will execute scripts in the
>   /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d directory in alphabetical order in
>   response to network events. Each script should be (a) a regular file,
>   (b) owned by root, (c) not writable by group or other, (d) not
>   set-uid, (e) and executable by the owner. Each script receives two
>   arguments, the first being the interface name of the device just
>   activated, and second an action.

Based on the man page there's the following "events": up, down, vpn-up, vpn-down, hostname, dhcp4-change, & dhcp6-change.

I suspect that you could do what you want using the "up" event. This blog post, titled: "[Use NetworkManager to Launch Scripts Based on Network Location](http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2008/12/18/use-networkmanager-launch-scripts-based-network-location/)", shows how you could construct a shell script to run when an interface, (eth0), goes up.

For example (code "borrowed" from that blog post):

```
#!/bin/sh
IF=$1
STATUS=$2
USER=justintime

wait_for_process() {
  PNAME=$1
  PID=`/usr/bin/pgrep $PNAME`
  while [ -z "$PID" ]; do
        sleep 3;
        PID=`/usr/bin/pgrep $PNAME`
  done
}

start_synergy() {
     wait_for_process nm-applet
     /bin/su $USER -c "/usr/bin/synergyc $1"
}

if [ "$IF" = "eth0" ] && [ "$STATUS" = "up" ]; then

        #LAN Subnet at work
        NETMASK="10.0.0.0/8"
        if [ -n "`/sbin/ip addr show $IF to $NETMASK`" ]; then
                ARGS="jentoo.bucklehq.com"
                start_synergy $ARGS
                exit $?
        fi

fi
```

This example should be enough to get you started in doing what you're trying to do.